# Add chars to existing array of chars/ char pointers?

Tags: c, file-io, char, execvp

Currently I am reading in a line of strings and parsing it. I'm using the following variables to do so: `char **parsed` and `char *parsed_arguments[64]`. Here is the code I use to parse it:

```
char newcommand []
parsed =  parsed_arguments;
*parsed++ = strtok(newcommand,SEPARATORS);   // tokenize input
while ((*parsed++ = strtok(NULL,SEPARATORS)))
```

That part is fine and dandy, but my problem arises when I try to add to parsed_arguments. What I'm trying to accomplish is reading text from a file, placing it in `char buffer[]`, tokenizing it, and adding it to `parsed_arguments` so I can pass those arguments to a program using `execvp`. So far I am able to read text and place it into my buffer and I've even tried tokenizing it, but the last part just confuses me. Here's more code detailing what I'm working on:

```
if(file_In)
  {
    //strcpy(input_File_Name,parsed_arguments[input_Index]);

    switch(pid =fork())
      {
      case -1:
        printf("fork error, aborting\n");
        abort();
      case 0:
        parsed_arguments[input_Index-1] = NULL; 
        input_File = freopen(parsed_arguments[input_Index],"r",stdin);
        fgets(buffer, 1023, input_File);

        buf =  parsed_buf;
        *buf++ = strtok(buffer,SEPARATORS);   // tokenize input
        while ((*buf++ = strtok(NULL,SEPARATORS)))

        //strcat(parsed, buf); // invalid

        printf("The buffer holds: %s\n", buffer);
        execvp(parsed_arguments[0],parsed_arguments);

        break;
      default:
        waitpid(pid,NULL,WUNTRACED);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overthinking this problem. Based on the parsing code at the top of your question, you have already solved the problem.

```
parsed =  parsed_arguments; 
/* parsed now points to the first element parsed_arguments */
*parsed++ = strtok(newcommand,SEPARATORS);   // tokenize input
while ((*parsed++ = strtok(NULL,SEPARATORS)))
    ; /* habit of mine */
/* At this point, parsed_arguments should be now populated with each
   token from newcommand by strtok
   Minus a few caveats, the following call should be valid */
execvp(parsed_arguments[0], parsed_arguments);
```

Before I describe the caveats that I mentioned (that I know of), I'll quickly explain **why** this should work:
`strtok` returns the pointer of the last token found in its first argument. This pointer is then written in this variable: `*parsed++` (which is an expression that evaluates into an l-value). This dereferences the address pointed to by `parsed`(which is an element of `parsed_arguments`). Finally, the post-fix `++` operator simply makes `parsed` point to the next element of `parsed_arguments` **after** the full expression is evaluated.

The important thing to note, is `parsed` points to the same block of memory occupied by `parsed_arguments`. By setting `parsed = parsed_arguments`, `*parsed = token` is equivalent to `parsed_arguments[some_index] = token`.

You could express your code (not quite as elegantly) without pointer arithmetic as such:

```
int argc = 0;
/* declarations, etc *SNIP* */
parsed_arguments[argc] = strtok(newcommand, delim);
while (parsed_arguments[argc++]) {
    parsed_arguments[argc] = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

I hope this is the answer you were looking for, or at least helps point you in the right direction, based on the actual code provided (since a lot is missing, for obvious reasons), and there is a `parsed_buf`, `buf`  that seem to mimic `parsed` and `parsed_arguments`, but those also exist in the code, I am not 100% sure if I completely understand what you are trying to do.

**Caveats**

`execvp(...)`'s documentation states that by convention, the first element of the arguments should be the file name (I see that you already know this), but nonetheless, make sure the program name is the first element--either have your file's content have the program name first, or just start from the second element.

`execvp(...)` also states that the last argument should be a NULL pointer. You can ensure this by a call to `memset(parsed_arguments, 0, sizeof(parsed_arguments));` and ensuring the file never specifies more than 64 arguments.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp

Lastly, (possibly nit-picking), `while (pointer)` works on the premise that `NULL == 0` (in most cases, it is `(void *) 0` AFAIK), I don't know how important it is to you, but if you ever run into an implementation where `NULL` is not defined as 0, it might cause some issues. So, it would be safer to write `while ((*parsed++ = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORS)) != NULL)`. My two cents anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm trying to do is to pass the contents of a file to the program as arguments. i.e. `./programname < filename`. Any idea how to do that? I believe it is similar to using a batch file.

Comment: `./programname < filename` (in Bash and cmd, anyway) simply redirects stdin of the program to the file (just as `./programname > filename` redirects stdout to the file)
Is that what you are trying to do? I thought you meant `file=some arg list`, then `./programname some arg list`. From what I know, if you want file redirection, after the call to fork() (if it succeeds), you simply need to open the file, copy the file descriptor to STDIN_FILENO (effectively replacing STDIN_FILENO) and then calling `execvp(...)` http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2 http://linux.die.net/man/3/open